# Does versionName have to be increasing?

Tags: android, google-play, versioning

I had uploaded these versions of my app to Google Play:

```
VersionCode             VersionName
       1                      1
       2                      2
       3                      3
       …
       15                     15
```

Now I plan to upload the version with

```
versionCode: 16
versionName: 1.6.1
```

Is this versionName allowed? (Or do I have to choose 16.1, so that versionNames are non-decreasing).

Comment: I do use version names like `android:versionName="1.15.06.16 b"` (major, year, month, day, release of the day). So, if I ask a user which version is shown in the About window, they can answer me correctly and I can debug THAT precise version. Having a = 1, ... z  = 26

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this versionName allowed?

Yes. `versionName` is purely to show users. It has no particular meaning to the system. You could go with `Turbo System 5000` and be fine too.